# Estimating number of read/write queries in mysql

Tags: mysql

Does Mysql provide any variable through which I can get the number of read and write queries served since server restart? Just want to estimate the Requests per second served by my db.

Answer (score 3):

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS WHERE Variable_name = 'Com_insert';
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS WHERE Variable_name = 'Com_select';
```

More information can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-status-variables.html).